# Can't archive app

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to create `.ipa` file. In [Distributing Apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW2) it is said that I should archive my app firstly. Then choose **`Product > Archive`**.

But this option is gray. Why?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the select-box near your play and stop buttons (upper right) you should choose the device instead of the simulator.

Either:

- Attach a physical device (iPhone, iPad) to the machine you are developing on and select that device.
- Select "Generic iOS Device"

Comment: You don't have to have the device plugged in, you can select the 'iOS Device' option.